The Barr-Kock lemma for regular 2-categories
There is a nice result for regular 1-categories, which I quote from page 441 of Borceux & Bourn's textbook "Mal'cev, Protomodular, Homological and Semi-Abelian Categories".

This is proved assuming Barr's embedding theorem for regular 1-categories to reduce to a diagram chase in $\operatorname{Set}$. However, there is a morally correct direct proof on page 22 of Bourn's textbook "From Groups to Categorial Algebra".
I am trying to prove an analogue of this lemma for regular 2-categories. We should substitute kernel pairs for comma kernel pairs and regular epics for eso maps. I only need this as a lemma on the way to proving an analog of the short five lemma in a nice class of 2-categories, so I am possibly willing to add some assumptions about the 1-cell $s$ or object $X$.
For an arbitrary regular 2-category, I can show that $A \to B \underset{Y}{\times} X$ is eso directly using the comma pasting lemma and the properties of a factorization system, vaguely analogously to the direct proof in Bourn. However, I haven't figured out how to show the map is ff, and (as far as I can see) neither the direct nor indirect proof of this generalize nicely. I believe I can prove this in the specific regular 2-category $\operatorname{Cat}$ by looking at the induced diagram of homsets for a pair of objects in $A$ and a reduction to the proof in Bourn-Borceux. Hence I can prove this for a regular 2-category that regularly embeds into some 2-category of 2-presheaves.
I'm hoping that perhaps this result is already known to some experts, or obvious in some way that I'm missing. It might have arisen in questions about 2-dimensional descent, since the 1-categorical result was originally useful in descent theory. I would settle for a nice wide class of regular 2-categories which regularly embed into 2-presheaf 2-categories, and a proof of such embedding.
